# onActivityResult, onResume и SharedPreferences вместе не работают

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Дорогие друзья, возникла проблема, помогите пожалуйста. В приложении есть активити с фрагментом, в котором происходит основное действие, а именно: есть несколько невидимых картинок и кнопка. При нажатии на кнопку нас перекидывает на другую активити, где просят ввести пин-код, мы вводим, и нас перебрасывает обратно (использую для этого onActivityResult), и картинка становится видимой.
Так как у нас несколько картинок, возникла необходимость сохранять их состояние (если свернуть, или закрыть приложение, и снова зайти в это активити - все картинки снова невидимые).
Я решил использовать для этого SharedPreferences, onResume и onPause.
Но возникла проблема: теперь картинка не становится видимой после ввода пин-кода и возвращении к первой активити. А если убрать проверку пин-кодом, и просто попросить кноку сделать картинку видимой, то все работает, и сохраняет.

Прикладываю кусочек кода:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private ImageView imageViewDoneOne, imageViewDoneTwo;

private SharedPreferences mSettings;
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "Settings";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_STAMP = "stamp1";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_STAMP2 = "stamp2";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);

    mSettings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    imageViewDoneOne = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.done_one);
    imageViewDoneTwo = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.done_two);
    view.findViewById(R.id.button_stamp).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (imageViewDoneOne.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                //Делаем картинку видимой без переносана в PinActivity и SharedPreferences работает
                imageViewDoneOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (imageViewDoneOne.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE &&
                    imageViewDoneTwo.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                //Делаем картинку видимой с переходом в PinActivity и SharedPreferences НЕработает
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PinActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data == null) {return;}

    int visi = data.getIntExtra("value", View.VISIBLE);
    if (imageViewDoneOne.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
        imageViewDoneOne.setVisibility(visi);
    } else if (imageViewDoneOne.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE &&
            imageViewDoneTwo.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
        imageViewDoneTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } 
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_STAMP)){
        imageViewDoneOne.setVisibility(mSettings.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_STAMP, 0));
    }

    if (mSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_STAMP2)){
        imageViewDoneTwo.setVisibility(mSettings.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_STAMP2, 0));
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
    editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_STAMP, imageViewDoneOne.getVisibility());
    editor.apply();
    editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_STAMP2, imageViewDoneTwo.getVisibility());
    editor.apply();
}  
}
```

PinActivity:

```
public class PinActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG = "PinLockView";

private PinLockView mPinLockView;
private IndicatorDots mIndicatorDots;
private String pinCode = "1234";
public static int visibility = View.VISIBLE;

private PinLockListener mPinLockListener = new PinLockListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String pin) {
        Intent answer = new Intent();
        Log.d(TAG, "Pin complete: " + pin);
        if (pin.equals(pinCode)) {
            answer.putExtra("value", visibility);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, answer);
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Wrong pin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEmpty() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Pin empty");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPinChange(int pinLength, String intermediatePin) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Pin changed, new length " + pinLength + " with intermediate pin " + intermediatePin);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pin);

    mPinLockView = (PinLockView) findViewById(R.id.pin_lock_view);
    mIndicatorDots = (IndicatorDots) findViewById(R.id.indicator_dots);


    mPinLockView.attachIndicatorDots(mIndicatorDots);
    mPinLockView.setPinLockListener(mPinLockListener);

    mPinLockView.setPinLength(4);
    mPinLockView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));

    mIndicatorDots.setIndicatorType(IndicatorDots.IndicatorType.FILL_WITH_ANIMATION);
}
```

}

Спасибо всем за внимание и простите, если вопрос глупый, так как только учусь!)

Comment: Добавьте код `PinActivity`.

Comment: @eugeneek добавил)

Comment: В `onActivityResult` вы устанавливаете верное значение видимости, а затем в `onResume`, перебиваете его значением из SharedPreference. Перенесите код из `onResume` в `onCreate`.

Comment: Спасибо @eugeneek, так и сделал. А также перенес все из onPause в onActivityResult, где "засунул" все настройки сразу после установки видимости. Теперь все РАБОТАЕТ!!!)

Answer (score 2):

Имейте в виду что сначала идет вызов метода `onActivityResult()`, а после `onResume()` который переопределяет видимость вашего изображения

Для сохранения состояния данных лучше использовать метод [`onSaveInstanceState`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html?hl=ru)

Comment: Обновил свой ответ

Comment: спасибо большое, я воспользовался Вашим советом (onSaveInstanceState) и помогло лишь для решения проблемы с переворотом экрана, но как только я перехожу на другой фрагмент, или покидаю активити, все пропадает.